# Why my current screen still appears for some time when i go back and come again in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am in a screen where I have to upload images. then I edited the image here and go back to previous screen and come again. now old image can see for some time then it replaced new image which is fetch from Api. how can I resolve this?

I am using Provider Consumer State Management.

Will I do anything in Provider when I click back button?

Comment: share some code ...

Comment: Yes some code but I think it's releated to the dispose method and Provider.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.